# How to make a variable in the where condition represent all values?

Tags: sql, birt

Code:

```
declare @fruit varchar(70)
set @fruit='apple'
select * from supermarket where fruitType=@fruit
```

How can I make it so that if the variable `@fruit` is set to `'ALL'` it will cause the select statement to retrieve all values in the table?

Answer (score 2):

If you write the query like this:

```
select * 
from supermarket 
where fruitType=@fruit OR @fruit = 'ALL'
```

then, in case `@fruit` is equal to `'ALL'`, the `WHERE` clause evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly check the `ALL` value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   supermarket 
WHERE  @fruit IN ('ALL', fruitType)
```